# Using views arguments to highlight/alter corresponding entries instead of filtering

Tags: 6, nodes, views

So, I am making a tree based tab style menu for a section of my site.

There are 3 content types with node references going up the tree. They are ordered: Section < Product < Package.

If I am on a package I want to display 3 tiers of tab at the top of the page, filtered by the section/product the package is in and with the section+product+package that the package is a child of highlighted.

eg: If I am looking at "SECTION1 PRODUCT2 PACKAGE3" it should display the tabs like this:

SECTION1 section2 section3

section1product1 SECTION1PRODUCT2 section1product3

section1product2package1 section1product2package2 SECTION1PRODUCT2PACKAGE3

with the capitalisation representing something akin to the "active"class in css

My URL aliases are formatted: `example.com/[sectionname]/[productname]/[packagename]`

Edit: Many paths have failed me thus far... Any generic advice welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just manually making a menu to display the same information... Surely there should be support for one of: node path aliases as arguments OR menu generation from nodereference tree OR menu generation from url aliases (ideally from only selected nodes)
Alas i found none of the above. I feel gross for creating the menu manually but there seemed to be no other way. Thanks for checking this out...